# How to mount a disk on key on Red-Hat 6 (Beta) after ejecting it

Tags: usb, mount, rhel, eject

I have a Cruzer disk on key which was recognized automatically by my RedHat6-beta OS.

I removed it always using the GUI option "Safely remove", but one time by mistake I selected "Eject" and from then it is not recognized.

I tried to mount it according to some Google's results, including editing the fstab file - no success.

Does someone have an idea how to solve that?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: how about unplugging and replugging?

Comment: @phunehehe - of course I tried it... Didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it after all.

First - run `dmesg` command -- a new SCSI device is recognized (usually sdb1). Then `mount /dev/sdb1 <mount point>`.